Read uid from all NFC cards in ios
I'm trying to retrieve the UID from an NFC card so that users can read it and assign it to a task in the database. However, I'm encountering a few problems:
I have two NFC cards, but with the NFC Tools app, I can only read one card, and only in compatibility mode.
Seems that some NFC cards may not work well with iOS, as both cards work correctly with Android. Is this likely a hardware issue with iOS, or could the NFC cards be too old? There's another way to achieve this?
I also tried using the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285425/read-uid-from-nfc-mifare-tag-ios-13
, but I encountered the error "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate'" and I can't get it to work.
Also downloaded several NFC apps to try to retrieve the UID, but or doesn't get detected or only reads the value I had written in 1 of the 2 cards (again in android both got detected and return the uid).
working nfc.
not working nfc
This is the swift code:
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class ViewController: UIViewController, NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate {

    var nfcSession: NFCTagReaderSession?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func startNFCScan(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            print("NFC no disponible en este dispositivo.")
            return
        }
        
        nfcSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: .iso14443, delegate: self)
        nfcSession?.alertMessage = "Acerca una etiqueta NFC."
        nfcSession?.begin()
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        let tag = tags.first!
        session.connect(to: tag, completionHandler: { error in
            if case let .miFare(miFare) = tag {
                var byteData = [UInt8]()
                miFare.identifier.withUnsafeBytes { byteData.append(contentsOf: $0) }
                var uid = "0"
                byteData.forEach {
                    uid.append(String($0, radix: 16))
                }
                print("UID: \(uid)")
            }
        })
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error en la sesión NFC: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}

